# "[SC] StartService FAILED 127:The specified procedure could not be found" on a functional driver

Tags: driver, windows-driver

I have been developing a driver for quite a while now. Yesterday when I logged off it was perfectly functional, was able of being run and did what it is supposed to.

Today, I didn't change a thing and just ran the driver to see the "The specified procedure could not be found." error code from the sc start command.

I am compiling the project on my host machine and then running the .sys in a VMware virtual machine. From what I have found, this error code means there is a missing dependency, however I didn't change a thing. How can this occur?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons, can be be due to API downgraded between the one used by WDK and the target Windows OS.

You can use dependency walker to check the downgraded API and try removing/substituting those APIs.

But, I would suggest to use a different WDK abeit a lower version one supporting your OS. This exact solution worked for me personally.